# Can't retrieve translation of gesture recognizer when set programatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to programmatically set the translation of a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in a `UIView` for a unit test, however, it doesn't seem to recognise the translation.

Here is my code for setting the translation:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
gestureRecognizer.state = .began
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
let translation = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(translation, in: view)
```

Then I pass both the gesture recognizer and the view to a function which uses this line of code:

```
let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view)
```

This always appears as `(0.0, 0.0)`, instead of `(10.0, 10.0)`. Why?!